# multiprocessing does not save data

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

My program essentially scrapes images off of websites that I made up.  I have 3 functions and each of them scrape images off of a specific website by using a parameter.  My program contains the following code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Process

img1 = []
img2 = []
img3 = []

def my_func1(img_search):
    del img1[:]

    url1 = "http://www.somewebsite.com/" + str(img_search)
    r1 = requests.get(url1)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content)
    data1 = soup1.find_all("div",{"class":"img"})

    for item in data1:
        try:
            img1.append(item.contents[0].find('img')['src'])
        except:
            img1.append("img Unknown")
    return

def my_func2(img_search):
    del img2[:]

    url2 = "http://www.somewebsite2.com/" + str(img_search)
    r2 = requests.get(url2)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content)
    data2 = soup2.find_all("div",{"class":"img"})

    for item in data2:
        try:
            img2.append(item.contents[0].find('img')['src'])
        except:
            img2.append("img Unknown")
    return

def my_func3(img_search):
    del img3[:]

    url3 = "http://www.somewebsite3.com/" + str(img_search)
    r3 = requests.get(url3)
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(r3.content)
    data3 = soup3.find_all("div",{"class":"img"})

    for item in data3:
        try:
            img3.append(item.contents[0].find('img')['src'])
        except:
            img3.append("img Unknown")
    return

my_func1("orange cat")
my_func2("blue cat")
my_func3("green cat")

print(*img1, sep='\n')
print(*img2, sep='\n')
print(*img3, sep='\n')
```

The scraping works just fine, but it is quite slow so I decided to use multiprocessing to speed it up, and multiprocessing did in fact speed it up.  I essentially replaced the function calls with this

```
p = Process(target=my_func1, args=("orange cat",))
p.start()
p2 = Process(target=my_func2, args=("blue cat",))
p2.start()
p3 = Process(target=my_func3, args=("green cat",))
p3.start()

p.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
```

However, when I print the img1 , img2, and img3 lists they are empty.  How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `multiprocessing` to distribute your work between several processes, each process will run in a separate namespace (a copy of the namespace of the main process). The changes you make in the child-process's namespace will not be reflected in the parent process's namespace. You'll need to use a `multiprocessing.Queue` or some other synchronization method to pass the data back from the worker processes.

In your example code, your three functions are almost exactly the same, only the web site's domain and the variable names differ. If that's how your real functions look, I suggest using `multiprocessing.Pool.map` and passing the whole URL to a single function, rather than just passing search terms:

```
def my_func(search_url):
    r = requests.get(search_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"img"})
    images = []
    for item in data:
        try:
            images.append(item.contents[0].find('img')['src'])
        except:
            images.append("img Unknown")
    return images

if __name__ == "__main__":
    searches = ['http://www.somewebsite1.com/?orange+cat', # or whatever
                'http://www.somewebsite2.com/?blue+cat',
                'http://www.somewebsite3.com/?green+cat']
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool() # will create as many processes as you have CPU cores
    results = pool.map(my_func, searches)
    pool.close()
    # do something with results, which will be a list with of the function return values
```

Comment: For my case, how would I use a queue to pass the data to my lists?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at your worker functions, I see they're almost identical. If that's not a simplification for Stack Overflow, I suggest replacing them with a single function and using `multiprocessing.Pool.map`. The `Pool` takes care of starting the processes and setting up queues for you. Even if you really do need separate worker functions, you could use `apply_async` on a `Pool`

Comment: I am currently using this documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html for help.  If you can, can you please demonstrate a quick simple example to guide me, it would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add some (untested) example code using `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Comment: @SagwaTheCat: You could use `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` that uses threads instead of processes. See whatever works best in your case.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for adding the example code, it helped a lot.  How would I access say the first element in the fist list.  For example, I know that I can print the first list by performing `print(result[0])`, but how would I print the first element in the first list.

Comment: @SagwaTheCat: You can do multiple indexing operations on a list of lists: `result[0][0]` is the first item from the first inner list.